# How to create a data source in Tableau from a BigQuery table protected by CMEK (customer managed key)?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, tableau-api

I have a BigQuery dataset in my GCP project.
Also, I use the cloud version of Tableau online.tableau.com

Case 1 - Google-managed keys - OK
I am able to create a data source into the Tableau from BigQuery table protected with Google-managed keys (default option).
And I see the content of the table.

Case 2 - CMEK - FAIL
I am able to create a data source into the Tableau from BigQuery table protected with CMEK.
But I cannot see the content of the table.
I have a message that the request rejected.

[image]

How to create a data source in Tableau from a BigQuery table protected by CMEK (customer-managed key)?

Answer (score 0):

I did another try.
Actually, the protected table is added and data available on sheets and dashboards.
The only issue that data preview during data source design does not work.